# Still cannot combine split with curly brackets

Tags: equations, brackets, split

I tried to use vphantom{...} and overleaf does not take breaqn package, so I still have the question:

I have the following formula, but I get an error with it that I can't fix. What is wrong here really?

```
 \begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
     \psi(x)=\sum_{j=1}^l\sum_{v=0}^{m_j-1}U_v(x,\mu)V_{m_j-1-v}(\psi,\mu)\left|_{\mu=\mu_j}\\
     +\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\mu}}{\pi\alpha(\sqrt{\mu})\alpha(-\sqrt{\mu})}\left\{e^+(x,\sqrt{\mu})e^+(\psi,-\sqrt{\mu})\\+e^-(x,\sqrt{\mu})e^-(\psi,\sqrt{-\mu})\right\}d\mu
  \end{split}
 \end{equation}
```

The preamble is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand\Setst[3][big]{\csname #1l\endcsname\{ #2 : 
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}#3\csname #1r\endcsname \}\end{array}}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=1, title=Alphabetical Index]


\newcommand{\footremember}[2]{%
    \footnote{#2}
    \newcounter{#1}
    \setcounter{#1}{\value{footnote}}%
}
\newcommand{\footrecall}[1]{%
    \footnotemark[\value{#1}]%
```

and the comment by overleaf is:

```
Extra }, or forgotten \right.
Missing \right. inserted.
Missing } inserted.
Extra \right.
Missing { inserted.
```

Thanks

Comment: It's the same problem as your previous question. You can't have `\left` and `\right` on different lines. Use manual sizing: `\biggl\{`, `\biggr\}` and so on.

Comment: As campa says `\left...\right` cannot span rows, so it is better to manually case. You are mentioning `\vphantom` which leads me to think you are trying to do open ended `\left...\right` in which case you need `\dots\right.` (note the dot) and `\left. \dots` (note the dot)

Comment: Additionally always post full (but minimal) examples that others can just copy and test as is. Here we have to guess the document class and preamble.

Comment: `\biggl |`  and `\bigl\{`    ... `\bigr\}` will work, presumably if you got an error then you made an error but we can not help with that if you just repost a fragment we can not run, that uses `\left..\right`

Comment: No please don't make external links. Edit the question to have a code section with a complete a small document that uses `\bigl\{`  and `\bigr\}` rather than `\left` and `\right`, and do not say "it does not work" give the exact error message that you get,

Comment: also overleaf does have all of texlive including `breqn` but you have mis-spelled it above as breakn  (but I wouldn't use breqn here)

Comment: Edited as required! Thanks!